# Hide/Show function not working on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, charts

Here's my load function

```
        $("html").load(function(){
            $.post("DumpsterService.php", function(result){     //da mettere url
                $("h2").append(data).each;
                });
            });

            $("#QuantitaDep").hide();
            $("#NumDepositi").hide(); 
        });
```

But when I load the page, everything is showen, I've also tried with ("canvas#QuantitaDep") and ("canvas#NymDepositi") but still not working

Here the canvas:

```
    <div class="numeroDepositi">
        <h2>Numero depositi:</h2>
        <canvas id="NumDepositi" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
        <script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById('NumDepositi').getContext('2d');
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',

            data: {
                labels: ['Lunedì', 'Martedì', 'Mercoledì', 'Giovedì', 'Venerdì', 'Sabato', 'Domenica'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Andamento',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45] //for example
                }]
            },

            // Configuration options go here
            options: {}
        });
        </script>
```

I shared only one of the canvas cause they are the same but

`<canvas id="QuantitaDep" width="300" height="100"></canvas>`

Please help me, I'm not understanding

Comment: Is this a typo: `$("h2").append(data).each;`? Do you have any console errors in the web inspector?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter doesn't give a syntax error (so no error in the console) - but it appears OP is asking about `.hide()` so no idea why they even included the `$.post` - it would be trivial for them to determine if that's causing the problem (by temporarily removing it) so we can *assume* it's not causing the problem and is just irrelevant (big assumption)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

instead of:

```
$("html").load(function(){
```

Also try to load your JS snippet just before the `</html>` tag, and if still not working, try to move it before your  `</head>` tag.

You should debug first if your jQuery is loading properly, you can try this adding this code between your `<head></head>` tags, with:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() { console.log( "document loaded" ); });

    $( window ).on( "load", function() { console.log( "window loaded" ); });
</script>
```

and open your browser console (F12 in Chrome) and check the console log, you should see `document loaded` or `window loaded` if your JS dependencies are fine.

jQuery documentation: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

You can try to load your `<canvas>` elements with no visibility by default just using CSS:

```
<canvas id="NumDepositi" name="NumDepositi" width="300" height="100" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;"></canvas>
```

and change to visible onClick with JS:

```
$('#NumDepositi').click(function() {
        $("#NumDepositi").show();
        $("#NumDepositi").css('visibility','visible');
        $("#NumDepositi").css('display','block');
    /* you can use 'this' instead, like:
        $(this).show();
        $(this).css('visibility','visible');
        $(this).css('display','block');
    */
});
```